# Close multiple files

Tags: file, fortran

I need to close and delete several files once they are open and the content stored in some variables. To avoid repeating the syntax can I use:

```
        OPEN(UNIT = 27, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/w.txt", status = "UNKNOWN")
  C
        READ(UNIT,END=1000) w
   1000 CLOSE (UNIT, status='delete') ,
```

So that I only need to specify `CLOSE (UNIT, status='delete')` once?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question right... Do you want to close and delete all *open* files at once?

Comment: I have to open 27 files and after reaching the end of each file I need to close and delete each one of them.

Comment: Well, you would need some logic in there to close and delete the *correct* file (`unit`). I personally wouldn't use the `end` statement, instead I would call a function that closes the correct file!

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I've used the `end` statement because otherwise my compiler issued an error saying `forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read`. Is there a way to solve this "end of file" issue using a function and not the `end` statement?

Comment: By using the `iostat` statement. `iostat>0` Is a read failure, `iostat==-1` is `end-of-file`, `iostat==-2` is `end-of-record`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use the end statement, instead I would call a subroutine that closes the correct file:

```
subroutine del_file(uFile, stat)
  implicit none
  integer uFile, stat 

c If the unit is not open, stat will be non-zero
  close(unit=uFile, status='delete', iostat=stat)
end subroutine
```

You're read statement then would be:

```
read(unit=curUnit, iostat=stat) w
if ( stat .ne. 0 ) call del_file(curUnit, stat)
```

You still would need some logic in there not to read from close files. I would recommend an array to hold all the units corresponding to the input files.

Comment: I'm getting `severe (29): file not found` now because I've added `action = "READ"` to the `OPEN` statement. I now might be hitting on the warning you wrote in your last paragraph: `You still would need some logic in there not to read from close files`. I think I need `action = "READ"` because sometimes I get an error  `permission to access file denied`.... so puzzled here with the basics..

Comment: I would use an `integer` array `units` to store the unit number of each file. I would initialize the array to `0`, and store the unit number of the `n`th process in `units(n)`. Upon closing (and deleting) the file, I would reset the corresponding entry to zero. Then, you could use `if (units(n).ne.0) read(unit=units(n),...)` to just read from *open* files.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the help. I modified the `READ` and `WRITE` to `READWRITE` and it helped. So now I don't have initial errors but unfortunately I eventually get the `severe (9): permission to access file denied` error later on. Will see if your tip solves this.

Answer (score 1):

You could, but you'd be doing everything between `1000 CLOSE...` and whatever called it next all over again. That is,

```
       READ(UNIT=27, END=1000)
1000   CLOSE(STATUS='delete')
       ... computations ...
       READ(UNIT=28, END=1000)
```

would cause you to do `... computations ...` all over again, which is probably what you *don't* want. It probably would be easier to either write the `CLOSE` command explicitly or, as Alexander said in the comments, write a function that closes the file, given a particular file ID, and deletes it:

```
FUNCTION FileClose(lun) RESULT(ierr)
   INTEGER :: lun, ierr
   CLOSE(lun, STATUS='delete', IOSTAT=ierr)
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Dancing on the edge of controversy here - but be mindful that functions with side effects like this may not be executed in the way a programmer might expect, given particular interpretations of the rules of the language - see F2008 7.1.7 for a taste.  With a subroutine things are much more certain.  Given all a function typically saves you is a little bit of typing and perhaps an extra variable at the point of reference, I'd be strongly inclined to completely avoid the issue and just use a subroutine.

Comment: @IanH: Controversy's my middle name ;). Personally, I'd just close & delete the file after I was done with it, rather than pass the buck to a subroutine.