# fortran error I/O

Tags: file, io, fortran

I get this error during runtime:

```
forrtl: severe (10): Cannot overwrite existing file, unit
27, file C:\Abaqus_JOBS\w.txt
```

The error occurs in the beginning of the analysis.
At the start, the file `w.txt` is created but is initially empty. Then `1` is written to `w.txt` and after I get the above error.

My code is:

```
 SUBROUTINE MAIN(....)
C
C UPDATE w counter
C
      flag = 0
      OPEN(2700, action = "READWRITE", FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/w.txt", status = "UNKNOWN")
C
      READ(2700, *, iostat=stat) w
      CALL del_file(2700, stat, flag)
C
      w = w + 1
      IF (w.GT.nELEM) THEN
        nInc = KINC !Update nInc: to check IF failure occurred
      ELSE
        nInc = 0
      ENDIF
C
      OPEN(2700, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/w.txt", 
     1 action = "READWRITE", status = "new")
C If I change ´status = "new"´ to `status = "unknown"´ it works...
      WRITE(2700,*) w
      CLOSE(2700)
C
C computations
C      
     RETURN
     END

  SUBROUTINE WMOD(....)
C Subroutine WMOD is called at the end of subroutine MAIN
C
C UPDATE w
    OPEN(27, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/w.txt",
 1  action = "READWRITE", status = "UNKNOWN")
    w1 = 0.D0
    WRITE(27,*) w1
    CLOSE(27)

C      
  RETURN
  END

  SUBROUTINE del_file(uFile, stat, flag)
 C
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER uFile, stat, flag 

  IF (stat.NE.0 .OR. flag.EQ.1) THEN
 C If the unit is not open, stat will be non-zero
    CLOSE(unit=uFile, status='delete', iostat=stat)
  ELSE
    CLOSE(unit=uFile, iostat=stat)
  ENDIF
 C
  END SUBROUTINE
```

Ref: [Close multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501394/close-multiple-files)

My question is why do I have to change `status = "new"` to `status = "unknown"` in `MAIN` to make this work?

After some runtime I also got `severe (9): permission to access file denied`, so puzzled with these errors. Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: ? Why do you want to read from an _empty_ file ?

Comment: @ja72: probably to test the `del_file` subroutine he copied from Alexander Vogt in the `Ref`'d SO question.

Comment: I don't think you get that error when compiling, it looks like a run-time error to me.

Comment: Related info @ http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Check_that_file_exists#Fortran http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Delete_a_file#Fortran

Comment: based on added code: when file exists you delete it, closing the unit. You need to close the unit in the case iostat=0, else later you are re-opening an already open unit.

Comment: @george: You are right! Now it works but I have to change `status = "new"` to `status = "unknown"` in `MAIN` to make it work... DO you know why?

Answer (score 3):

You are telling the code that it is formatted (implicit definition of `FORM` in the `OPEN` statement), but you are trying to read it as a unformatted text by using `READ(27)`.

This should read

```
OPEN(UNIT = 27, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/w.txt", status = "UNKNOWN")
READ(27, *, iostat=stat) w
```

Comment: that error sounds like it is a associated with a write. Are you sure you are showing all relevant code?

Comment: I second @george's request for more of the code that produces this issue.

Comment: @Kyle,@george: Added extra code and new developements. I just really want to open some files, write stuff to it and then change their content based on some computations.